# Is direct GET good? How to make it?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view that handles a ListView and a from, it uses GET and returns filtered things depending on their tags on the same page. Here is it:

```
class AllView(AjaxListView):

context_object_name = 'smth'
template_name = 'blog/all_things.html'
page_template = 'blog/things.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    form = TagForm(self.request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        self.tag_name = (form.cleaned_data['tag']).lower()
        return self.send_results(self.tag_name)
    else:
        self.tag_name = "All"
        return Fact.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AllView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if 'TagForm' not in context:
        context['TagForm'] = TagForm()
    context['tag'] = self.tag_name
    return context

def send_results(self, tag):
    return Fact.objects.filter(tags__slug=tag)
```

and now and want to make just the same thing but with a simple link .
For example I have `<a>Food</a>` and i want it to go to `?tag=food`. I have done a very stupid thing, but it works:
URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<tag>[\w-]+)$', views.TagView, name='tag'),
```

View:

```
def TagView(request, tag):
# change this someday...
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:all') + '?tag={}'.format(tag))
```

I understand that this is stupid, so is there any wise way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you don't need the second view and url pattern. You could check for the existence of the 'tag' parameter and create the queryset according to that.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.GET.get('tag'):
        self.tag_name = self.request.GET['tag']
        return self.send_results(self.tag_name)
    else:
       self.tag_name = "All"
       return Fact.objects.all()
```

For a hard coded link in the template's HTML you could use:

```
<a href="{% url 'your_view' %}?tag=AAA">Tag AAA</a>
```

Comment: yes, but also I am interested in how this link should look in a template, what href='' does it need to have  could you help with this?)

Comment: I've expanded the answer a bit, does it help you now?

Comment: Just what i've wanted! Thank you!